# pydicom error found file when using pydicom.dcmread(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)

Tags: python, package, pydicom

I am starting to use the pydicom package. I am following the instructions here https://medium.com/@hengloose/a-comprehensive-starter-guide-to-visualizing-and-analyzing-dicom-images-in-python-7a8430fcb7ed
But I cannot figure out why I always get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

when it comes to this line

```
pydicom.dcmread(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)
```

I am using the ubuntu bash on windows 10 and when I use the ls command, the dicom file is not shown, even though I can see it on the regular browser.

The file I am using is downloaded from here https://www.theobjects.com/dragonfly/learn-sample-datasets.html

thank you for your help

update:

I notice that If I try to get another dicom file in the Ubuntu directory, it is not found in the ubuntu bash, but it is still found in windows (both with the browser and the cmd)

output of `dir` in the cdm windows

```
04/14/2020  09:50 PM    <DIR>          .
04/14/2020  09:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/11/2020  11:56 AM    <DIR>          .git
04/11/2020  11:56 AM             1,305 .gitignore
04/11/2020  11:56 AM             1,366 COPYRIGHT.md
04/14/2020  08:36 PM    <DIR>          deepmedic
04/11/2020  11:56 AM            10,670 deepMedicRun
04/11/2020  11:56 AM    <DIR>          documentation
04/11/2020  06:12 PM    <DIR>          examples
04/11/2020  11:56 AM             1,493 LICENSE.txt
04/11/2020  11:56 AM               231 MANIFEST.in
04/14/2020  09:45 PM    <DIR>          MR_BRAIN
04/11/2020  11:56 AM            42,152 plotTrainingProgress.py
04/11/2020  11:56 AM                23 README.md
04/11/2020  11:56 AM                40 setup.cfg
04/11/2020  11:56 AM             1,407 setup.py
04/14/2020  09:20 PM           356,394 test.dcm
04/14/2020  09:20 PM             2,789 testDicom.py
              11 File(s)        417,870 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  18,907,107,328 bytes free
```

The output of `ls` in my ubuntu bash

```
COPYRIGHT.md  LICENSE.txt  MANIFEST.in  README.md  deepMedicRun  deepmedic  documentation  examples  plotTrainingProgress.py  setup.cfg  setup.py  testDicom.py
```

The file is test.dmc

Comment: This looks like a problem with the file system layout, not with pydicom. Can you show the output of `dir` in your directory in a regular DOS shell, and the output of `ls` in your bash?

Comment: Ok, I see now, the file is `test.dcm`. You probably need something like `ls -la` in your bash to see all files, maybe it is hidden? Also you seem to iterate over the contents of your project directory, where only one DICOM file exists; the rest of the files will probably raise `InvalidDicomError` if used as described.

Comment: What happens if you just call `pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(path, 'test.dcm')`?